# how to start Asychoronous task in a thread finally block in android

Tags: android, asynchronous, threadpool

i want to start Asynchoronous task after some sleep time. For that i am using thread and i start my asynchronous task in that thread finally block. But it gives cant create a handler inside a thread exception.

i am using the following logic.

```
 thread= new Thread() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                   try 
                   {
                      int waited = 0;
                      while (waited < 300) 
                      {
                         sleep(100);
                         waited += 100;                                          
                      }
                   } 
                   catch (InterruptedException e) 
                   {
                      // do nothing
                   }
                   finally 
                   {     

                     Load ld=new Load();
                  ld.execute();
                   }
                }
            };
            thread.start();
```

Comment: Use Handler.post or handler.postDelayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, if the final goal is to run AsyncTask after some delay, I would use [Handler.postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) instead of creating separate `Thread` and sleeping there:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new Load().execute();
    }
}, 300); //300ms timeout
```

But, if you really wanna make fun of Android, you can create [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) - special thread which has looper in it, so your `AsyncTask` will not be complaining anymore:

```
thread= new HandlerThread("my_thread") 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
               try 
               {
                  int waited = 0;
                  while (waited < 300) 
                  {
                     sleep(100);
                     waited += 100;                                          
                  }
               } 
               catch (InterruptedException e) 
               {
                  // do nothing
               }
               finally 
               {     

                 Load ld=new Load();
                 ld.execute();
               }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
```

Please note that you are responsible for calling `quit()` on this thread. Also I'm not sure what happens if you quit this thread before AsyncTask is done. I don't remember where AsyncTask posts its results - to the main thread, or to the thread it was called from...
In any case, second option is just a mess, so don't do it:) Use the first one

Comment: Really? What is SPLASH_TIMEOUT?

Comment: copypaste from another answer

Answer (score 0):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do whatever you want. 
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

}
```

You can use like above. there SPLASH_TIME_OUT is the millisecond value that u want to make a delay.

Answer (score 0):

Use Handler class, and define Runnable YourAsyncTask that will contain code executed after sleepTime

```
mHandler.postDelayed(YourAsyncTask, sleepTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must run AsyncTask in UI thread, so you can use something like this:

```
class YourThread extends Thread{
private Activity _activity;
public YourThread(Activity _activity){
this activity =  _activity;}
public void run() 
                {
                   try 
                   {
                      int waited = 0;
                      while (waited < 300) 
                      {
                         sleep(100);
                         waited += 100;                                          
                      }
                   } 
                   catch (InterruptedException e) 
                   {
                      // do nothing
                   }
                   finally 
                   {     
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Load ld=new Load();
                  ld.execute();
            }
        });
                   }
                }
}
```

and in your activity call thread like this:

```
YourThread thread = new YourThread(this);
thread.start();
```

also note: use soft reference to activity or do not forget kill thred when activity will be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

just do your like below code:
define a thread globally.

```
 public static Thread thread;

    thread= new Thread() {
    public void run() {

    sleep(time);

    Message msg = setTextHandler.obtainMessage(2);                                                 
    setTextHandler.sendMessage(msg);

     }
  };
  thread.start();
```

and your handler look like

```
 private final Handler setTextHandler = new Handler() {
 @Override
 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      if (thread!= null) {
          thread.interrupt();
          thread= null;
      }
      switch (msg.what) {
        case 2: //do your work here
                Load ld=new Load();
                ld.execute();
                break;
      }
    }
 };
```